# JSP pop up showing previous / old values

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee

My requirement is I have one data table on the JSP page in which one column is student and values are link there. If user click on link then pop up should open and provide the student details.

In popup I need to maintain look and feel like my other pages ( css etc ) so this means I cannot open normal default windows popup.

When I am loading the jsp using load function of jQuery. Jsp is calling only once so when my trying to  fetching the dynamic  content next time then previous value is showing on popup

```
$jScript("#DetailPopUpContainer").load('../admin/DetailPopUp', function() {
    $jScript(this).dialog({ 
        autoOpen: true,
        //height:540,
        width:680,
        //loadUrl: 'http://xyz/admin/popup',
        position: [250, 150],
        modal: true,
        cache: false 
    });
```

Please help.

Comment: you should to pass a random number as a parameter to the URL to make it unique. As long as the system finds same URL, it returns cached value and not from DB fetch.

Comment: can you please give some example

Comment: @hermanth Why not properly configure your web server to not allow caching for this page. Random numbers may repeat "at random", so this is a bad workaround. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421485/ui-not-updating-when-using-tomcat-with-apache-mod-jk/27422004#27422004

Comment: Its browse behaviour and nothing to do with server configuration. Instead of changing browser settings(its not possible at client machines too!), this could be better approach to pass random value. It may not repeat "at random", as it is associated with session.

Comment: I think we can take current date timestamp as random value. That will always unique.

Comment: @ hemanth : Thanks Hemanth. Issue fixed now. FYI.. I have used jScript.now() instead of Math.random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding one parameter to the URL which will pass random number every time to make it unique like below. To suit jquery syntax, you may need to adjust the code(`ran=Math.random())`

```
$jScript("#DetailPopUpContainer").load('../admin/DetailPopUp?rand='+Math.random(), function() {
                 $jScript(this).dialog({ 
                       autoOpen: true,
                       //height:540,
                       width:680,
                       //loadUrl: 'http://xyz/admin/popup',
                       position: [250, 150],
                       modal: true,
                       cache: false 


                 });
```

Comment: For random number between 1 and 1000: `var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);`. No need to give a parameter name, just to avoid caching: `'../admin/DetailPopUp' + '?' + rand`

Comment: Ofcorse, by simply passing random value to the URL also makes sense. For simplicity assigned a name to it.

Comment: Random numbers are a hack, consider proper cache configuration, see my comment below the question.